# Decorator for the row in Python

Tags: python, decorator, python-decorators

A function f prints a text file. How you can build a decorator that puts a number in front of the row? I've tried to add a number at the start of a line, but it just made a mess from the text file.

Comment: Hi DSS, how may we help you. Where is the function **f()**?

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need a decorator, but if you want you can make one.

Following code will print the line number and text. I have used `enumerate` function which iterates over file as a list of lines and returns the text and index starting from 1.

```
with open('./file.txt','r') as file:
    for line_number, text in enumerate(file, start=1): # thanks to  Mustafa Aydın
        print(str(line_number) + " : " +text, end="")
```

**Output**

```
1 : this
2 : file
3 : contains
4 : 5
5 : lines
```